# How to stop MATLAB from resizing or scaling the image when using refline

Tags: image, matlab, resize, plot, scaling

I have been searching around for this, but I can't figure how to stop MATLAB from resizing my image when I use the refline command. The line is drawn perfectly, but my image is shrunk to an extremely small size in order to fit the line and image in the window. Is there a way to stop MATLAB from doing this when I call on the refline command?

For example: 
imshow('picture')
userline=refline((really big number let says 99),2); 
set(userline, 'Color', 'm', 'Linewidth', 2)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the limits of the axes to be the same as they were before `refline` was called.

```
plot(1:10)
ax = gca;
refline(0.5,-1)
set(gca,'Ylim',get(ax,'Ylim'))
set(gca,'Xlim',get(ax,'Xlim'))
```

Comment: The refline function doesn't change the limits of the image. However, when I do use it the image is made smaller in my window in order to fit the whole line. I'm not sure how to expand my image. The magnify glass only enlarges the image within that area instead of enlarging my image so I can take a nice piture

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question to include an example. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: For example: imshow('picture'); userline=refline((really big number let says 99),2);
        set(userline, 'Color', 'm', 'Linewidth', 2)

Comment: This would resize my image and crop the axis so that all I can see is a line and hardly my picture. Do you have any idea how to fix this? I've tried what you said, but it doesn't seem to change the axes. Or maybe it isn't an axes problem?